# How to cache a URL content via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache

I am new to this thing, how can I cache the content of a URL? Via .htaccess or anything? Actually, I have a URL like this **example.com/cache.js**  on my blog.

I want to cache it so it should not load again and again from the server.

Comment: This is too broad to answer, there are many ways to cache content. If you want to do it at the Apache level, then there are caching modules available. What sort of performance improvements are you seeking? Do you actually need the speed up?

Comment: If you just don't want a browser to re-load a simple file, look into HTTP cache headers to instruct browsers not to reload them. Or put the file on a CDN, which will do this for you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control